# Avoiding heat death in an accelerated expanding universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology, space-expansion

Would there be any way to avoid heat death in an accelerated expanding universe?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_death_of_the_universe

Is the heat death of the universe completely unavoidable in an universe with an accelerated expansion dominated by dark energy like ours?

Or could it be avoided according to current knowledge, observations and experiments in physics?

Comment: Have a look at the *Opposing views* section of the Wikipedia page you cited. Already the content of that section can suggest ways to avoid heat death of the universe.

Comment: I have often wondered why the concept of "infinite divisibility" has not (to my knowledge) been explicitly employed in the evasion of "heat death", so I like the question:  However, as the wiki about such divisibility does not mention energy as one of the items that might be infinitely divided, some flaw in my reasoning might perhaps be found, maybe in the "energy conditions" formulated by Hawking & Penrose.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know exactly how the universe will face its fate, whether through big rip or heat death, although heat death seems more plausible.

Note that heat death exactly isn't caused by accelerated expansion by dark energy but is a manifestation of [thermodynamic's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics). It states that all systems will eventually reach the state of maximum entropy or disorders, so nothing ordered structures like stars, planets maybe even atoms would remain. The universe will become uniform everywhere.

Considering we can't *escape* our universe, or some entirely new theory points to something else entirely changing, the physics as we know, **NO** We can't dodge the fate of our universe,